# Generate UUID column with a UDF and then split into two dataframes with common UUID column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe containing info about people with columns `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email_addresses`, where `email_addresses` is a comma separated list of email addresses. The data looks something like this:

| first_name | last_name | email_addresses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Doe | jane.doe@example.com,doe.jane@example.com |
| John | Smith | john.smith@example.com,smith.john@example.com |

I'm trying to split this into two dataframes by first adding a `person_id` column populated with UUIDs using a UDF, and then creating a new dataframe by doing a `split` and `explode` on the `email_addresses` column.

My code looks something like this:

```
from uuid import uuid4
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

uuid_udf = F.udf(lambda: str(uuid4()), StringType()).asNondeterministic()

df = ingest_data_from_csv() # Imagine this function populates a dataframe from a CSV

df_with_id = df.withColumn("person_id", uuid_udf())

person_df = df_with_id.drop("email_addresses")

email_df = (
    df_with_id.drop("first_name", "last_name")
    .withColumn("email_address", F.explode(F.split(F.col("email_addresses"), ",")))
    .drop("email_addresses")
```

I thought this would give me two data frames with a foreign key type of relationship that look something like this:

| person_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 | Jane | Doe |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 | John | Smith |

| person_id | email_address |
| --- | --- |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 | jane.doe@example.com |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 | doe.jane@example.com |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 | john.smith@example.com |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 | smith.john@example.com |

but what I end up with is different values in all the `person_id` columns, looking something like this:

| person_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 | Jane | Doe |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 | John | Smith |

| person_id | email_address |
| --- | --- |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003 | jane.doe@example.com |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004 | doe.jane@example.com |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000005 | john.smith@example.com |
| 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000006 | smith.john@example.com |

Is there a way to implement this "foreign key" type of relationship with pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache` the dataframe so that the results will not change when you call the Python functions again. Also you can call the `uuid` spark SQL function with `F.expr('uuid()')`:

```
df_with_id = df.withColumn("id", F.expr('uuid()'))
# or if you want to use your udf,
# df_with_id = df.withColumn("id", uuid_udf())

df_with_id.cache()   ### IMPORTANT!

person_df = df_with_id.drop("email_addresses")
email_df = (
    df_with_id.drop("first_name", "last_name")
    .withColumn("email_address", F.explode(F.split(F.col("email_addresses"), ",")))
    .drop("email_addresses")
)

email_df.show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|       email_address|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|389fb85d-338f-469...|jane.doe@example.com|
|389fb85d-338f-469...|doe.jane@example.com|
|6600abe9-8087-420...|john.smith@exampl...|
|6600abe9-8087-420...|smith.john@exampl...|
+--------------------+--------------------+

person_df.show()
+----------+---------+--------------------+
|first_name|last_name|                  id|
+----------+---------+--------------------+
|      Jane|      Doe|389fb85d-338f-469...|
|      John|    Smith|6600abe9-8087-420...|
+----------+---------+--------------------+
```

Comment: This is pretty much the solution that I found, but I used `.persist` instead of `.cache`. Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: @Sean basically the same, except that you can specify cache options if you use persist - see the docs for more details: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.persist and https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `sha2` function of Spark by creating a hash value of `first_name` and `last_name`. Please note that, I have also added `monotonically_increasing_id` to create a hash value. This, I am using because if `first_name` and `last_name` are coming similar, then we should not have a similar hash value.

**Code:**

```
from uuid import uuid4
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("D:/DataAnalysis/person.csv")
    
df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------+
|first_name|last_name|email_addresses                              |
+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------+
|Jane      |Doe      |jane.doe@example.com,doe.jane@example.com    |
|John      |Smith    |john.smith@example.com,smith.john@example.com|
+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------+
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sha2, concat 

df_with_id = df.withColumn("uid", sha2(concat(F.monotonically_increasing_id(),col("first_name"), col("last_name")), 256))

df_with_id.show(truncate=False)
+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|first_name|last_name|email_addresses                              |uid                                                             |
+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Jane      |Doe      |jane.doe@example.com,doe.jane@example.com    |ed9d106bca3c383d07e00bbc147cb2a6625e198a0eadd275017b1c152b617a20|
|John      |Smith    |john.smith@example.com,smith.john@example.com|001fb8d89c60d70c9e24d6122efc0b2c85450c8009ab1936f231055c54ccf7e6|
+----------+---------+---------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+

person_df = df_with_id.drop("email_addresses")

person_df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|first_name|last_name|uid                                                             |
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Jane      |Doe      |ed9d106bca3c383d07e00bbc147cb2a6625e198a0eadd275017b1c152b617a20|
|John      |Smith    |001fb8d89c60d70c9e24d6122efc0b2c85450c8009ab1936f231055c54ccf7e6|
+----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+

email_df = (
    df_with_id.drop("first_name", "last_name")
    .withColumn("email_address", F.explode(F.split(F.col("email_addresses"), ",")))
    .drop("email_addresses")
    )   

email_df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|uid                                                             |email_address         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|ed9d106bca3c383d07e00bbc147cb2a6625e198a0eadd275017b1c152b617a20|jane.doe@example.com  |
|ed9d106bca3c383d07e00bbc147cb2a6625e198a0eadd275017b1c152b617a20|doe.jane@example.com  |
|001fb8d89c60d70c9e24d6122efc0b2c85450c8009ab1936f231055c54ccf7e6|john.smith@example.com|
|001fb8d89c60d70c9e24d6122efc0b2c85450c8009ab1936f231055c54ccf7e6|smith.john@example.com|
+----------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: This wouldn't work in my use case because there may be people with the same name but different email addresses in the data set.

Comment: You can include the email (if distinct enough) as a part of the hash

Comment: I have already handled/tested the same name use case by using `monotonically_increasing_id` . You can test it.

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde Ah, I see. Sorry, I missed that part. Seems you could just hash the ID then?

Comment: Yes. We can also achieve this with only `monotonically_increasing_id`. But for more unique Id I have added `first_name` and `last_name`